# Restcomm ClassCastException during creating SBB child relation

Tags: parent-child, classcastexception, rhino, restcomm, jain-slee

I'm trying to create SBB child on Restcomm, most of the times I encounter this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:  
com.edafa.slee.http.sbb.api.HttpSbbLocalObjectImpl cannot be cast to  
com.edafa.slee.http.sbb.api.HttpSbbLocalObject
```

> Where *HttpSbbLocalObject* is the sbb-local-object of the child SBB

**Kindly find some useful information which may help you to answer me:**

- *HttpSbbLocalObject* in a separate library named *http-sbb-api-lib*
- this is the library-ref in the child sbb-jar.xml:
     `<library-ref>
          <library-name>http-sbb-api-lib</library-name>
          <library-vendor>Edafa</library-vendor>
          <library-version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</library-version>
      </library-ref>`
- this is the sbb-local-interface declaration in the child sbb-jar.xml:
      `<sbb-local-interface>
            <sbb-local-interface-name>
                   com.edafa.slee.http.sbb.api.HttpSbbLocalObject
            </sbb-local-interface-name>
   </sbb-local-interface>`
- this is the library-ref in the parent sbb-jar.xml:
   `<library-ref>
          <library-name>http-sbb-api-lib</library-name>
          <library-vendor>Edafa</library-vendor>
          <library-version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</library-version>
     </library-ref>`
- this is the sbb-ref in the parent sbb-jar.xml:
   `<sbb-ref>
          <sbb-name>http-sbb</sbb-name>
          <sbb-vendor>Edafa</sbb-vendor>
          <sbb-version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</sbb-version>
          <sbb-alias>http-sbb-child</sbb-alias>
      </sbb-ref>`
- this is the child-relation-method in the parent sbb-jar.xml:
   `<get-child-relation-method>
         <sbb-alias-ref>http-sbb-child</sbb-alias-ref>
         <get-child-relation-method-name>
                 getHttpActorLocalObject
         </get-child-relation-method-name>
         <default-priority>0</default-priority>
   </get-child-relation-method>`
- this is the child-relation-method-declaration in the parent SBB:
   `public abstract ChildRelation getHttpActorLocalObject();`
- this is the child creation in parent:
   `httpSbbLocalObject=(HttpSbbLocalObject)  getHttpActorLocalObject().create();`
- on the above point the exception happened
   `"java.lang.ClassCastException:  com.edafa.slee.http.sbb.api.HttpSbbLocalObjectImpl cannot be cast to  com.edafa.slee.http.sbb.api.HttpSbbLocalObject"`

I tried many trials to solve this problem but unfortunately there's no useful result.

**Kindly find some useful notes which you must consider:**

- *HttpSbbLocalObject* is the sbb-local-object of the child SBB
- this problem happen on runtime not on deployment
- sometimes the SBB child created successfully by redeploying all the DUs
- I tried the same DUs successfully on *Opencloud-Rhino* without any issue
- I use restcomm-slee-7.2.0-158.76-wildfly-10.1.0.Final

Please I need any useful piece of advice which help me to solve this exception